# Python: AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: python, list

I'm adaptying the code of a guy that studies with me, for my problem.

This is his code:

```
     if not((paux1 == paux2).all()):
        pop[int(saidaFO[pos,0]),:] = paux2
        pos -= 1
```

And it works, and when I give a print, I have this result by paux1: [-2.3668  1.3174].
I'm working in a different problem, and in my case, when I print paux1, I have this: [0.2107491848569726, 443, 3]

So, when I try to do the same comparation:

`if not((paux1 == paux2).all()):`

I got this error: "AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all' "
I'm not understand what is going on... Could someone help me, please?
I didn't understand so well how the .all() works... Maybe a equivalent code can work...

Comment: What types of objects are paux1 and paux2 in the original code, _exactly_?

Comment: Hello, please read [How do i ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). With the given info, we are not able to reproduce it. "bool"s really don't have any "all" method.

Comment: In the original code, the "if" sentence was placed inside a loop? .any(), .all() are used when you have multiple elements to try.

Comment: Sorry guys, I have began python a really little time ago... So that's why I was not able to provide all the importants informations that you said.  But the answer by Guimoute fixed my problem.

Comment: I have this problem yet with two 2D numpy arrays (m, 3) , (n, 3).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your guy's code, `paux1` and `paux2` are probably numpy arrays, so `paux1 == paux2` returns an array representing booleans (whether the tested equality is true or false), and that array does have a `.all()` method.

It sounds like you are working with lists, so `paux1 == paux2` does not compare elements by elements like numpy arrays do. You are only checking if both lists are equal, with returns a **single** boolean. This boolean does not have a `.all()` method and that's what causes your error.

Convert your lists of values beforehand to numpy arrays and the error should be fixed.

```
paux1 = np.array(paux1)
paux2 = np.array(paux2)
```

Comment: Guimoute, how is the correct way to do the same thing than "all()" do, without convert the lists? Because this solution resolve the problem in this place, but cause a compatiblity problem* in another part of the code.

Comment: `if all(x1 == x2 for (x1, x2) in zip(paux1, paux2)):` assuming they have the same length.

Comment: Note that regardless of the method, you might encounter issues if you check equality between float numbers unfortunately. Like 1 != 1.00000000001

Comment: Thank you!!! I have made a test, and 'if (paux1==paux2)' also works!

Answer (score 7):

Another source of error is if the two np.array don't have the same shape. For instance:

```
(np.array([[1,1]])==np.array([1,2,3])).all()
```

returns:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-400-ea9825114062> in <module>
----> 1 (np.array([[1,1]])==np.array([1,2,3])).all()

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Comment: Hey this is a good observation, do you know by any chance how to compare two numpy arrays to see if the shapes are different?

Comment: @skrhee in numpy you can do `assert arr1.shape == arr2.shape`